# How to parse plain content as Multipart request

Tags: java, httprequest, multipartform-data

I have this plain content and need to parse it as multipart request, Is there any way to do this?

```
------WebKitFormBoundaryTiKiuCl5MwiqSo2Q

Content-Disposition: form-data; name="myccd"; filename="1122.xml"
Content-Type: text/xml

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<?xml-stylesheet type="text/xsl" href="cda.xsl"?>
<ClinicalDocument xmlns="urn:hl7-org:v3" xmlns:sdtc="urn:hl7-org:sdtc" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="urn:hl7-org:v3../../../CDA%20R2/cda-schemas-and-samples/infrastructure/cda/CDA.xsd" classCode="DOCCLIN" moodCode="EVN">
   <realmCode code="US" />
 <templateId root="2.16.840.1.113883.10.20.22.2.45" />
 <code code="69730-0" codeSystem="2.16.840.1.113883.6.1" displayName="Instructions" />
               <title>Instructions</title>
               <text>
                  <paragraph>No data available for this section</paragraph>
               </text>
            </section>
         </component>
      </structuredBody>
   </component>
</ClinicalDocument>

------WebKitFormBoundaryTiKiuCl5MwiqSo2Q

Content-Disposition: form-data; name="patient_mrn"


1122

------WebKitFormBoundaryTiKiuCl5MwiqSo2Q--
```

Comment: It seems you are going to upload a file, so start [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/tutorial/doc/glrbb.html).

Comment: No, I am not going to upload file, I need an FormDataMultipart Request object from this xml text. I alredy have this text.